# How to include external packages in SCons

Tags: cmake, scons

I would like to know the proper way for building a project using SCons when it depends on external packages.

Consider the following program hello_world.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "external_package/external_header.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::cout<<"Hello World!"<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I could build it using CMake through the following CMakeLists.txt file

```
find_package(external_package REQUIRED)

include_directories(${external_package_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(hello_world hello_world.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hello_world ${external_package_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS hello_world
  DESTINATION bin)
```

What would be an equivalent SConstruct file? In particular, how to emulate the find_package functionality?

This is what I came up so far. Sconstruct

```
 env = Environment()
 env.Append(CPPPATH = [])
 env.Append(LIB_PATH=[])
 env.Program("hello_world", ["hello_world.cpp"])
```

I think that I should populate CPPPATH with ${external_package_INCLUDE_DIRS} and LIBPATH with ${external_package_LIB_DIRS}, but I do not get how to automatically find them.

UPDATE: my question is not very clear.
I would like to have a SConstruct file which does the same as the provided CMake. It has to build a project which has an external dependency.

Comment: So as I understand it find_package() works by locating a file named Find<package>.cmake in the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.  Are you asking if SCons can load a cmake find package file? Or something else?

Comment: I'm asking how should I create a Sconstruct file which produces the same result as the CMakeLists one. My intuition is that I need somehow the lists of files ${external_package_INCLUDE_DIRS} and ${external_package_LIBRARIES}, which in the working example are created through find_package()

Comment: Using the `pkg-config` subsystem could be an option. Does your external package provide a corresponding config file?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement find_package()? Or merely a reasonable way to set per package include path and libraries?

Comment: @bdbaddog the second.    Thanks

Comment: @dirkbaechle could you please provide an example of how to check for the existence of such a file and how to use pkg-config for my purpose?  Thanks

Comment: If you want to use pkg-config, then that's really a different question than how to pick a method to name variables for packages to be used.   Still you could use the tool method listed in my answer below to separate the pkg-config.  See ParseFlags here: (https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#f-ParseFlags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a few ways you could do this:

1) Have an prefix for environment variables you use to specify the packages paths etc. Assuming you'll include some logic which sets the PACKAGE_A_INCLUDE_DIRS,etc.

```
env = Environment()
env.AppendUnique(CPPPATH = '$PACKAGE_A_INCLUDE_DIRS')
env.AppendUnique(LIBPATH = '$PACKAGE_A_LIBS')
env.Program("hello_world", ["hello_world.cpp"])
```

2) Use a tool to set the required variables. This is a usage which may not match the name "tool", but others have used this well.

```
env = Environment()
env.Tool('PACKAGE_A')
env.Program("hello_world", ["hello_world.cpp"])
```

Then in site_scons/site_tools, you'd have a file named PACKAGE_A.py as follows:

```
def exists(env):
    return True

def generate(env):
    env.AppendUnique('LIBPATH'=['/path/to/libs'])
    env.AppendUnique('CPPPATH'=['/path/to/headers',...])
```

Then you can simple add env.Tool('some_package') to each Environment which should use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However this would require me to manually specify the path to the headers and libs, which are dependent on how a user has installed this package. Is there a way for Scons for automatically locating those files (as CMake does) ? Thanks again

Comment: cmake looks for Find<package>.cmake files.  So are you asking if SCons can use these?  Or would using pkg-config files work? In which case ParseFlags() should work, and as I said in my comment to your original questions you could wrap those in a Tool..  Basically any solution which doesn't use the Find<PACKAGE>.cmake files will require either a) knowledge of where they are install specified as above. b) use of pkg-config files, c) some method of extracting the information from other sources.  However are such packages are in your sandbox and you just need refer relative to the top?

Comment: You might try clarifying your original question further.  If my answer is correct, then your question might be more clearly "How can I use scons to manage adding flags for other packages to my build environment?"  Because my answer doesn't strictly answer how to do what your cmake does.